# Create admin role and user by installer

Tags: magento-1.9, user-roles, install-script, admin-user

I want to create admin role and assign a user to it with only sales and catalog resources by installer is any one having idea for this.

Answer (score -1):

Here we create admin user role programmatically by custom module installer with specific resources.

**First you need to create a installer file name InstallData.php in our custom module Setup folder**

complete path:

> app/code/ModuleNameSpace/YourModuleName/Setup

```
    <?php 
    namespace ModuleNameSpace\YourModuleName\Setup; 

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface; 

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface; 

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface; 

    /* For get RoleType and UserType for create Role */; 
    use Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl\Role\Group as RoleGroup; 

    use Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface; 

    /** * @codeCoverageIgnore */ 

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface { 

    /** * RoleFactory * * @var roleFactory */ 

    private $roleFactory; 

    /** * RulesFactory * * @var rulesFactory */ 

    private $rulesFactory; 

    /** * Init * * @param \Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory $roleFactory * @param \Magento\Authorization\Model\RulesFactory $rulesFactory */ 

    public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory $roleFactory, /* Instance of Role*/
 \Magento\Authorization\Model\RulesFactory $rulesFactory /* Instance of Rule */ 
/*this define that which resource permitted to wich role */ ) { 
    $this->roleFactory = $roleFactory; 
    $this->rulesFactory = $rulesFactory; 
    } 

    /** * {@inheritdoc} * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength) */ 

    public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context) { 
    /** * Create Warehouse role */
   $role=$this->roleFactory->create();
   $role->setName('YourRoleName') //Set Role Name Which you want to create 

   ->setPid(0) //set parent role id of your role 
   ->setRoleType(RoleGroup::ROLE_TYPE) 
   ->setUserType(UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_ADMIN); 

    $role->save(); 
    /* Now we set that which resources we allow to this role */ $resource=[
        'Magento_Backend::admin',
                    'Magento_Sales::sales',
                    'Magento_Sales::create',
                    'Magento_Sales::actions_view',  //you will use resource id which you want to allow

                    'Magento_Sales::cancel'
       ]; 

    /* Array of resource ids which we want to allow this role*/ 
    $this->rulesFactory->create()->setRoleId($role->getId())->setResources($resource)->saveRel(); 
    } 
    }
```

You can get resource ids from the following grep (run this in your magento root folder)

```
egrep -hiIro --exclude='*.php' --exclude='.bash_history' --exclude='./src/vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests' --exclude='./src/dev/tests/*' '<resource ref="([A-Za-z\_]*::[A-Za-z\_]*)"' ./vendor 2> /dev/null |less
```

After adding these file install your custom module in your magento2 instance

then by terminal run following command in your magento2 root directory

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Now  your admin user role created  you can check it  from **System > Permission > User Role**.

[Reference: Create user role programmatically using custom module installer](https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-create-user-role-programmatically-by-custom-module-installer/)

Comment: It is not working